# Implementing the electric and magnetic field into a 2d simulation of free particles

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, physics

I'm looking to introduce electrodynamics into my former ideal gas simulation, which is simply a bunch of particles inside a rectangle.

Edit it appears I was using the wrong equations, and that was the cause of my inital problem.

I'm  using the python 3.5 IDLE environment, `numpy` for the vector math and `pygame` for the visualization. The equations I'm using are:
 [electric field](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=moving+point+charge+electric+field) and [magnetic field](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=moving+point+charge+magnetic+field)

So far so good, my code is running. But to realisticly recreate the physics, the fields need to expand with velocity `c`. Additionally, when computing the force, I´d have to use the data from the retarded time, but it gets rewritten every new frame. Can I store that data or is it to memory heavy?
 What method do you suggest ?

The code uses the Ball class whose instances are the particles. It has a method associated to it which computes `E(r)` and `B(r)`. To compute the force acting on the particle `i`, I add all of them together at `i`´s  position and compute the force acting on `i`.

Here's the code, where 'mass' serves as radius of the particle aswell as charge and the z dimension is just added for the cross product.  The relevant code is the one affected by the `if electrodynamics == true` statement:

```
import pygame
import time
import random as r
import numpy as np

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

electrodynamics = True
show_field = False

Ball_num = 7
c = 10
red = (255,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('bouncy')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def normalized(a):
    b = np.linalg.norm(a)
    if not(b == 0):
        return a/b
    else:
        return np.zeros((1,3), dtype = float)

def tot_EM_field_at_charge(charges, charge):

    EM = np.array([[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]], dtype = float)

    for q in charges:
        EM = EM + q.EM_field(charge.position)

    return EM

def Force_on_bally(field, charge):
    c = np.cross(charge.velocity, field[1])
    force = charge.mass*(field[0] + np.cross(charge.velocity, field[1]))
    return force

class arrow(object):

    def __init__(self, length, x, y, charges):


        self.length = length
        self.position = np.array([x,y,0])

        self.field = tot_EM_field_at_charge(charges, self)
        self.field_mag= np.linalg.norm(self.field[0])
        if self.field_mag == 0:            
            self.field_direction = np.zeros(3,)
        else:    
            self.field_direction = self.field[0]/self.field_mag

        self.position_end()
        self.color()
        self.show()
    def position_end(self):

        self.position_2 = self.position + self.field_direction * self.length

        return self.position_2

    def color(self):
        self.color = self.field_mag
        if self.color < 0.05:
            self.color = (46,120,255)
        elif self.color < 0.1:
            self.color = (147,145,252)
        elif self.color < 0.3:
            self.color = (249,23,28)
        elif self.color < 0.6:
            self.color =(251,139,33) 
        elif self.color < 1:
            self.color = (255,255,127)
        else:
            self.color = (255,255,255)


        return self.color
    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, self.color,(int(self.position[0]), int(self.position[1])), (int(self.position_2[0]), int(self.position_2[1])))








class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, m, c, v_x, v_y):
        self.position = np.array([x,y,0], dtype = float)
        self.position_2 = np.array([x,y,0], dtype = float)
        self.velocity = np.array([v_x, v_y,0], dtype = float)
        self.velocity_2 = np.array([v_x, v_y,0], dtype = float)
        self.acceleration = np.array([0.,0.,0.], dtype = float)
        self.mass = m
        self.color = c

    def acceleration_compute(self,force):
        a = force/self.mass
        self.acceleration += a

    def move(self):
        self.velocity += self.acceleration
        self.position += self.velocity
        self.acceleration *= 0

    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, self.color, [int(self.position[0]), int(self.position[1])], self.mass)

    def Edgelord(self):
        if ((self.position[0] + self.velocity[0] >= display_width-self.mass) and self.velocity[0] > 0):
            self.velocity[0] *= -1
            self.position[0] = display_width - self.mass + self.velocity[0]


        elif ((self.position[0] + self.velocity[0] - self.mass  <= 0) and self.velocity[0] < 0 ):

            self.velocity[0] *= -1
            self.position[0] = self.mass + self.velocity[0] 


        elif ((self.position[1] + self.velocity[1] >= display_height - self.mass) and self.velocity[1] > 0):

            self.velocity[1] *= -1
            self.position[1] = display_height - self.mass + self.velocity[1]


        elif ((self.position[1] + self.velocity[1] - self.mass  <= 0) and self.velocity[1] < 0 ):

            self.position[1] = self.mass -self.velocity[1]
            self.velocity[1] *= -1

    def EM_field(self, R):
        radius = np.linalg.norm(R - self.position)
        if radius != 0:
            unitradius = (R - self.position)/radius
        else:
            unitradius = np.zeros(3, )

        if np.linalg.norm(radius) != 0 and np.dot(unitradius, self.velocity)!=1:
            charge      = self.mass / (1 - np.dot(unitradius, self.velocity) ** 3)


            if radius < self.mass:
                radius = self.mass

            radius2     = radius ** 2

            velocity_in_c = self.velocity/c

            oneMinusV2  = 1 - np.dot(velocity_in_c, velocity_in_c)
            uMinusV     = unitradius - velocity_in_c
            aCrossUmV   = np.cross(uMinusV, self.acceleration);
            Eleft       = (oneMinusV2 * (unitradius - velocity_in_c)) / radius2
            Eright      = np.cross(unitradius, aCrossUmV) / (radius*c**2)
            E           = charge * (Eleft - Eright)
            #E = np.zeros(3, )
            B           = np.cross(unitradius/c, ((charge*c**2) * (Eleft - Eright)))

            EM_field = np.array([E,B], dtype = float)
        else:
            EM_field = np.zeros((2,3), dtype = float)

        return EM_field

ballys = []

for i in range(Ball_num):
    #ballys.insert(i, Ball(r.randrange(300,display_width - 5, 10),r.randrange(200,display_height/2,1)   , r.randrange(5,10,1),(r.randint(1,255),r.randint(1,255),r.randint(1,255)), r.randint(-200,200)/1000, r.randint(-200,200)/1000))
    ballys.insert(i, Ball(200 + i*50, 220 + i*20 , 10,(r.randint(1,255),r.randint(1,255),r.randint(1,255)),0, 0 ))
#ballys.append( Ball(300 + 50, 300, 10,(r.randint(1,255),r.randint(1,255),r.randint(1,255)),10, 0 )) 

up = np.zeros(3,)
down = np.zeros(3,)
right = np.array([0.,0.,0.])
left = np.array([0.,0.,0.])
grav = np.array([0.,0.1,0.])
repulsion = np.array([0.,0.,0.])

crashed = False

while not crashed :

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                left = np.array([-0.1, 0.,0.])
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                right = np.array([0.1,0.,0.])
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                down = np.array([0.,0.1,0.])
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                up = np.array([0.,-0.1,0.])

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN :
                right = np.array([0.,0.,0.])
                left = np.array([0.,0.,0.])
                down = np.zeros(3,)
                up = np.zeros(3,)

    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    if show_field == True:
        for i in range(display_width//20):
            for j in range(display_height//20):
                arry = arrow(8, 10 + i*20, 10 + j*20 , ballys)



    if electrodynamics == True:
        for bally in ballys:
            bally.acceleration_compute(Force_on_bally(tot_EM_field_at_charge(ballys, bally), bally))

    for i, bally in enumerate(ballys):

        #if electrodynamics == True:
          #  bally.acceleration_compute(Force_on_bally(tot_EM_field_at_charge(ballys, bally), bally))
        bally.Edgelord()

        bally.acceleration_compute(up)
        bally.acceleration_compute(down)
        bally.acceleration_compute(right)
        bally.acceleration_compute(left)

        #ballys[i].acceleration_compute(grav * ballys[i].mass)

        for bally2 in ballys[i+1:]:

            #checks collisions
            if  np.linalg.norm(bally.position - bally2.position) <= bally.mass  + bally2.mass  :

                bally.velocity_2 = (bally.mass * bally.velocity + bally2.mass * bally2.velocity + bally2.mass *(bally2.velocity - bally.velocity))/ (bally.mass + bally2.mass)
                bally2.velocity_2 = (bally.mass * bally2.velocity + bally.mass * bally.velocity + bally.mass *(bally.velocity - bally2.velocity))/ (bally2.mass + bally.mass)

                #prevents balls getting stuck in each other and assignes new velocitys
                if not(np.linalg.norm(bally.position + bally.velocity_2  - (bally2.position + bally2.velocity_2) ) <= bally.mass  + bally2.mass):
                        bally.velocity = bally.velocity_2
                        bally2.velocity = bally2.velocity_2

        bally.Edgelord()

        bally.move()
        bally.show()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Where are those equations from ? Do they come from a paper ? This could clarify stuff

Comment: `return force * 1e-5` your final force value is hardly more than 5e-4 on `x` axis, I guess this is why it has "a negligible effect". I don't know this subject so I cannot really guess what type of values or effect you aim to obtain, but multiplying by `1e-4` or `1e-3` seems to have more effect on the simulation

Comment: My source ishttp://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath576/kmath576.htm

Comment: BTW the "explosion" does not seem that random. The closer two particles get, the greater the repulsive force. So my guess is that after accumulating enough speed, two particles end up getting really close and the divisions by the `r` and `r²` gives huge values

Comment: Sorry I accidently pressed enter.                                                              My source is http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath576/kmath576.htm, I believe I also saw these equations in 'The Feynman lectures on physics'. Regarding the negligible effect you are right. I just made the force smaller to counteract the 'large force'. Leaving this factor out makes it work till the 'large force' kicks in.

Comment: I think thats not it since the particles can perfectly collide

Comment: Yes they can collide, but you check for the collision after computing the force. So if the velocities are large enough to get the particles close enough, you will end up with huge velocities. This is not exactly tunneling, but the idea is similar

Comment: @Ezrael Interesting problem, really takes me back to high school physics class! I have a couple of questions about the simulation. First, is it safe to assume that we are only dealing with point masses? And second, what, if any, are there uniform fields (such as gravity, magnetic, and electrical) being applied to the simulation box? I saw that there was a defined gravity applied in the simulation, but is there gravity between each of the particles as well?

Comment: Regarding the first question, since the charge itself is not extended in space  (it is only at position x,y,z) I believe that assumption to be valid. Uniform fields such as near field gravity are applied but, for the sake  of testing, they are turned off.  Other fields are yet to be implemented. Considering that the simulation now works without external forces, except that my bad edge checking still makes it collapse, I believe that the problem has something to do with the particle not following the negative gradient of the field.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I assumed the problem was coming from the `1/r` and `1/r²` computations. Indeed, whem you divide by a really small value, you end up getting really large values, which can make your simulation explode.

Having a small `r` value happens when your particles have enough velocity to come really close to each other. You then solve the collision between them, but the damage is already done. You compute both forces, integrate them for the new velocity, then solve the collision and inverse velocities if needed, but the velocities are already huge.

To validate my assumption, I just tried to prevent the `radius` used in the computation to be too large, e.g.:

```
if radius < ball.mass:
    radius = ball.mass
```

I ran the simulation with 11 particles (which was exploding in like 1 or 2 minutes without this). The simulation has been running for 15 minutes or so, and has not exploded yet (and won't).

BTW, to make sure the problem was not coming from what you observed in your edit, I commented out the line `ballys[i].acceleration_compute(grav * ballys[i].mass)`. It appears the simulation still explodes without it (and is also stable when making sure the radius is not too small)

EDIT: [Here is the code I ran and from which I observed a correct behaviour](https://gist.github.com/Zouch/7442f8e07b5290c27fdc9169bae5bcc8)

Comment: When checking `radius` with `self.mass`, simulating 3 Balls on one axis caused them to feel almost no acceleration even with the artificial forces (left and right). Adding some other balls which arent on the same axis caused `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`. Also, running the programm without this check and other forces the simulation still explodes even tho the particles are far away from each other. May I ask you post the code you ran because what I did doesn't work for me.

Comment: [Here it is](https://gist.github.com/Zouch/7442f8e07b5290c27fdc9169bae5bcc8) Fun fact, I forgot to stop the simulation since my answer and it is still running correctly

Comment: It works! But calling the balls with initial velocitys and using other forces lets it explode, so there is still something that doesn't work as intended.